# Mathematically adding multiple lists

Tags: c#

I am stuck on a method where I have a `List<List<int>>` and would like to take each `List<int>`'s value of each index and add them together.
To be specific:

```
intList1[0] + intList2[0] + intList3[0]  
intList1[1] + intList2[1] + intList3[1]
```

Although the amount of list and a number of items in each list are not fixed. 
The result should then be a `List<int>` that contains each sum.

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Linq expression SelectMany can merge lists.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to simply merge lists.

Comment: So you want the sum of the sub lists?  Can you include some example data and expected output to make it more clear?

Comment: @juharr I understand he wants "column" sums.

Comment: I have the feeling that `List<List<int>>` wasn't the best design choice.

Comment: Sorry, I did not keep my not working code. I'll try ask my question better next time. But @Isuka 's post answered my question.

Comment: If you have more of these calculations and always need to bend and twist that list to get your desired output, you might want to put some effort into making up a better model for your data ... which also could improve performance on these calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Init your result list at the same size as the maximum number of elements in your sublists, and then simply loop into your sublists to sum the different values.

```
int maximumNumberElements = listContainer.Max(l => l.Count);
List<int> resultList = new List<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < maximumNumberElements; i++)
{
    resultList.Add(0);
}

for(int i = 0; i < listContainer.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < listContainer[i].Count; j++)
    {
        resultList[j] += listContainer[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: This could use a check to ensure that no sublist is shorter than `listContainer[0]`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett And what if one is larger?

Comment: @Fildor Good question. Maybe the list of sums should be `listContainer.Max(l => l.Count)` and the loop should fill in zeroes for missing values in the sublists. OP should specify that. Also, lsuka, this shouldn't be calling `.Count()`; `List<T>` has the `Count` property.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The answer has been modified using your suggestions.

Comment: @Fildor The issue should be fixed now.

Comment: @lsuka You're also going to need ensure that `j` is in range for `listContainer[0].Count`, since (thanks Fildor) OP does specify that the sublists will be of different sizes.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The second for is using the size of every specific sublist to navigate through them, so there shouldn't be any problem here.

Comment: Problem was coming from the fact the list size was directly initialized with the result of the LINQ line. It is working now: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kKe8wy.

Comment: @Isuka Derp! Thanks. Already upvoted you a while back though.

Answer (score 3):

You can union all `lists` together via `SelectMany` and then group them by initial `index` with subsequent `Sum()` calculating:

```
var answer = lists.SelectMany(x => x.Select((item,index) => new {item,index}).ToList())
       .GroupBy(x => x.index).Select(x => x.Sum(y => y.item)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the dictionary method for these kinds of issues, you could also store some interesting things alongside your value for the dictionary like, the number of items that summed up for that index etc.

```
// Dictionary of indexes to sums
var sums = new Dictionary<int, int>();

// Iterate your lists.
foreach(var list in lists) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
        // For the given index, sum up the values in the dictionary.
        if (sums.TryGetValue(i, var out value) == false) sums[i] = 0;
        sums[i] = sums[i] + list[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution perhaps better in case of larger lists

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ListSum(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> ll)
{
    var resultList = new List<int>();
    var enumerators = ll.Select(l => l.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    bool stillResult;
    do
    {
        stillResult = false;
        var sum = 0;
        foreach (var e in enumerators)
        {
            if (e.MoveNext())
            {
                sum += e.Current;
                stillResult = true;
            }
        }
        resultList.Add(sum);
    } while (stillResult);

    return resultList;
}
```